# Dextro or laevo-rotatory compound conversion

Tags: stereochemistry

Will applying an external electric field to a racemic mixture will convert the optically active compound(mixture of both Dextro and laevo-rotatory) into a particular dextro or laevo-rotatory compound?
I thought that if I apply an external field, then all the chiral molecules will arrange in a particular direction i.e their spatial arrangement in the solution aligns in a specific direction, resulting in a particular dextro or laevo-rotatory compound.
Is my thinking right or I am misunderstanding the topic?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the topic. Electric field isn't chiral, hence the result of its action isn't either.

Comment: @IvanNeretin it can be, for instance circularly polarized light has chirality.

Comment: This question is unclear as written because "arrange" is not well-defined enough. What do you mean to say that they arrange? Are you inverting centers? Are you causing reactions?

Comment: @Tyberius What "it"? We were talking about an electric field, not about circularly polarized light.

Comment: @IvanNeretin maybe I'm misunderstanding, but circularly polarized light is a chiral electromagnetic wave. Thus I would think you could apply a chiral electric field.

Comment: @Tyberius Electric field is a vector; how can it be chiral? Well, it kinda can, if you would rotate it with high frequency, at the same time moving pretty fast through the media (that's what light does, after all). But that would be an awfully broad interpretation of the words _"apply an external field"_.

Comment: @Zhe They are just two enantiomers of each other. Do even the $(\pm)$ enantiomers react with each other? Also, the OP has said "their spatial arrangement in the solution aligns in a specific direction". What more clarity is required?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I am a high-grade student, so I couldn't understand the point when you said electric field isn't chiral, does it mean electric field around a particular molecule is symmetric? by the way, I mentioned that I applied an external field, which I thought would orient all the molecules in a particular direction such that when I pass  a PPL through the solution, the polarimeter needle aligns in a particular direction unlike when I pass through a racemic mixture...

Comment: @IvanNeretin en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization. Circularly polarized light is used fairly commonly in chiral spectroscopy, like circular dichroism. Electric field is a vector with a polarization, which can vary with time such that the vector moves in circle (or more generally an ellipse).

Comment: @GaurangTandon If there is interconversion, how does it take place? Photochemical or a reversible equilibrium? If the former, it might be possible to generate a large enough gradient. Via the latter, you will have no chance because the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: @PrathamArya Yes, that's precisely the case: the situation with molecules in a **static** electric field is symmetric. But if the field isn't static and moves in a fashion I've described earlier (as it does in the circularly polarized light), or if you add some other influence that would break the symmetry, then yes, chirality might emerge.

Comment: @ivanneretin so can I conclude that if I managed to apply a static electric field, all the molecules of racemic mixture are arranged in a fashion like either dextro or laevo-rotatory at that particular moment..